# embed swf on web page

Tags: html, flash

I'm looking for a good way to embed an *.swf movie into my web site. I have tried several things but don't seem to get it to work, what I currently have is:

SWFObject dynamic embed - step 3

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  swfobject.embedSWF("/_resources/jwPlayer/player.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="myContent">
<p>Alternative content</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

but all I see ibn my browser is "Alternative content". What's going on? How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The script is in the `head` and the `div` is in the body, so when the browser executes the script, it hasn't loaded the `div` yet and fails. Move the script below the `div`.

Comment: tried this: `http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/sites/default/files/video.html` still doesn't work...

Comment: @cerr: `swfobject.js` does not exist.

Comment: so what do I need to put there?

Comment: @cerr: You need to download `swfobject.js` and put it in the same directory as the HTML file.

Comment: Well I added it now but the movie doesn't seem to play: `http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/sites/default/files/video.html`

Comment: @cerr: jwPlayer needs to be configured. Read their documentation for more information.